# Is there a way of optimizing that "addEventListener" block of code?

Tags: javascript

in an HTML page, i've got 7 buttons whit the following IDs: **#I, #II, #III, #IV, #V, #VI, #VII** placed in a **rContainer** div. 
I want to set the **iActiveButton** variable in correlation with the touched button. 
My code seems to work properly but i feel that it could be enhanced and shortened.
Any idea?

```
var iActiveButton;

function touchHandler(){
  console.log(iActiveButton);
}

rContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){

  I.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 1;}, false);
  II.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 2;}, false);
  III.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 3;}, false);
  IV.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 4;}, false);
  V.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 5;}, false);
  VI.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 6;}, false);
  VII.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = 7;}, false);

  touchHandler();

}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add event listeners to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981437/how-to-add-event-listeners-to-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: _“My code seems to work properly”_ - but it isn’t really “proper”, because every time touchstart occurs on rContainer, you add a _new_ touchstart listener to all those buttons. Since you’re only assigning a value to a variable, that doesn’t actually hurt - but it doesn’t make much sense to begin with.

Comment: All those standalone variable names are quite a code smell too - if possible, change them so you can grab them all at once with `querySelectorAll`, then iterate through them

Comment: Adding to the comments above, iterate over them and use a `for` loop with `let` keyword to assign the listeners. This is important that you use `let` and not `var`.

Comment: If this is code you've written, and you want a review of all aspects of the code, and you're willing to share a [mre] of the code, you should read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/13492) and [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to see if the question is on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: [Don't rely on element IDs becoming global variables!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25325221/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to look at the event target of the outer event listener.

```
rContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event){
  const targetId = event.target.getAttribute('id');

  // don't set iActiveButton if you clicked empty space inside `rContainer`
  if (targetId) {
    // romanNumeralMap looks like { 'I': 1, 'II': 2, etc... }
    iActiveButton = romanNumeralMap[targetId];
  }

  touchHandler();
}, false);
```

While this does require mapping from roman numerals to regular numbers, this way you are only adding one event listener!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the logic of your code like that and just want a refactor, I would go with this:

```
const buttonArray = [I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII];
rContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
  buttonArray.forEach((button, index) => {
    button.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){iActiveButton = index;}, false);
  }

  touchHandler();
}, false);
```

But I completely agree with the comments, adding new EventListeners on every event seems strange.